# my onClickListener is not working

Tags: android, onclicklistener

this is my MainActivity.java
    /*
     * Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     */
     package com.example.android.miwok;

```
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.TextView;


 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView numbers1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.numbers);
    assert numbers1 != null;
    numbers1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent number_intent =new    Intent(MainActivity.this,NumbersActivity.class);
            startActivity(number_intent);
        }
    });

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView family=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.family);
    assert family != null;
    family.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent family_intent=new   Intent(MainActivity.this,FamilyActivity.class);
             startActivity(family_intent);
        }
    });

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView colors=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.colors);
    assert colors != null;
    colors.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent color_intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ColorsActivity.class);
            startActivity(color_intent);
        }
    });

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView phrases=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.phrases);
    assert phrases != null;
    phrases.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent phrases_intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,PhrasesActivity.class);
            startActivity(phrases_intent);
          }
        });
    }


}
```

and my main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Copyright (C) 2016 The Android   Open Source Project

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@color/tan_background"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numbers"
    style="@style/CategoryStyle"
    android:background="@color/category_numbers"
    android:text="@string/category_numbers" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/family"
    style="@style/CategoryStyle"
    android:background="@color/category_family"
    android:text="@string/category_family" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/colors"
    style="@style/CategoryStyle"
    android:background="@color/category_colors"
    android:text="@string/category_colors" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phrases"
    style="@style/CategoryStyle"
    android:background="@color/category_phrases"
    android:text="@string/category_phrases" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and whe i run this app there is no error there is no warings but when i click on my text view its not going to the any other activity except phrases text view, it is working for phrases textview

Answer (score 0):

Why you are setting   `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` again and again

just set it once below the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     .
     .
     .
    }
```

Comment: i havenot enough batch or reputation

Answer (score 0):

```
mport android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.indianic.signaturestylo.R;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView numbers1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.numbers);
        assert numbers1 != null;
        numbers1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent number_intent =new    Intent(MainActivity.this,NumbersActivity.class);
                startActivity(number_intent);
            }
        });


        TextView family=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.family);
        assert family != null;
        family.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent family_intent=new   Intent(MainActivity.this,FamilyActivity.class);
                startActivity(family_intent);
            }
        });


        TextView colors=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.colors);
        assert colors != null;
        colors.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent color_intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ColorsActivity.class);
                startActivity(color_intent);
            }
        });


        TextView phrases=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.phrases);
        assert phrases != null;
        phrases.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent phrases_intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,PhrasesActivity.class);
                startActivity(phrases_intent);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

**Change Your java coe with this it will work fine.**